# If $|f(z)| < 1$ then $|f(z)| < |z|$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Exercise** Suppose $f(z)$ is analytic on $|z| <1$ and $|f(z)| < 1$ for all $|z| < 1$; also $f(0) = 0$. Show that $|f(z)| \leq |z|$ and that $|f'(0)| = 1$.

*Proof Attempt.*

First, I attempt to show that $|f(z)| \leq |z|$.

**Case 1: |z| =0:** If $z = 0$, then $f(0) = 0$. Notice that $|f(0)| = 0 \leq |0| = 0$.

**Case 2: 0<|z|<1:** ???

It's hard to imagine how Case 2 holds, given the below counterexample

Consider  for $|z| < 1$ the function $f(z) = z + \frac{|z-1|}{2}$
. Then for all $ 0<|z| < 1$, we have $|f(z)| < 1$ **but** $|f(z)| > |z|$. Perhaps there is something I am misunderstanding here?? Any help or tips are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The statement is false. Just take $f(z)=z$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I apologize, there was a typo. The statement was meant to say $|f(z)| \leq |z|$, not $|f(z)| < |z|$. I have fixed it

Comment: Then your statement is the [Schwarz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma).

Comment: $z+\frac{|z-1|}2$ isn’t analytic, is it?

Comment: Also, your example is not holomorphic, ... The point is that this is Schwarz' lemma, and if $f(z)=0$ then $f(z)/z$ has a removable singularity at $0$... It's not super-difficult to complete the argument, but it's not utterly trivial, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider (analytic!) function $g(z) = f(z)/z$. Using maximum modulus principle (i.e. that analytic function modulus takes maximum on boundary) one can easily see that $|g(z)| \leq 1$ for $|z|<1$. Hence $|f(z)| \leq |z|$

Answer (score 1):

Use the Riemann mapping on removable singularities to show that $f(z)/z$ can be extended to an analytic function, and use the max principle on the disk centered at 0 of radius $0<r<1$. You will get a bound that holds for every $0<r<1$, and then take a suitable limit to get your bound.
Now, your example is not a holomorphic function. One quick way to see this: if it were, then $f(z)-z$ would be a holomorphic real valued function defined on a open connected set. What does the open mapping theorem tell you? Of course, you can still use the CR equations to show that.